# Request an url not allowed for get status code from the response

Tags: python, callback, scrapy

I'm looking a solution for making a request on an not allowed domain for checking the outbound links.

But my function "parse_outboundLinks" is never called.

I must modify the allowed domain ?

Thanks for your help

My code :

```
    name = "mySpider"
    allowed_domains = ["monsite.fr"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.monsite.fr/"]
    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=()),follow='true',callback='parse_item')]

    def parse_item(self, response):
        xlink = SgmlLinkExtractor(deny_domains=(self.allowed_domains[0]))
        for link in xlink.extract_links(response):
            Request(link.url, callback=self.parse_outboundLinks)

   def parse_outboundLinks(self, response):
         print response.status
```

Comment: Did you debug your parse_item? Are there any links in xlink?

Comment: The parse_item works. i've all links in xlinks like that "http://www.otherdomains.tld" , but the function parse_outboundLinks is never called.

Comment: well then keep on debugging and see where it breaks. Get familiar with for example pdb http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html

Comment: Thanks Puciek fo you help.

The filter on duplicate url is active by default

I,ve just modified my request like that and yield the request.

    yield Request(link.url, callback=self.parse_outboundLinks, dont_filter=True)

Comment: You are welcome and have fun.

Comment: Did you check the logs? When I run your code I'm getting a `sgmllib.SGMLParseError: unexpected ':' char in declaration error`.

Comment: Hi, I'm getting none error

Answer (score 0):

Parse Function will get called only if `yield` is specified.
Change `Request(link.url, callback=self.parse_outboundLinks)` to `yield Request(link.url, callback=self.parse_outboundLinks)`

Similar problem in other threads.
[scrapy's Request function is not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17631190/scrapys-request-function-is-not-being-called/17632995#17632995)